# VBA output previous folder name in field

Tags: vba, list, file, ms-access, directory

I'm having trouble with figuring out how to get the name of a folder to output to a separate field in MS Access. So far I've managed to use this Allen Browne script and tweaked it to output the file name and the path as one field.

All of the files in this search are contained within sub folders, and it is important to output the last sub folder name in a separate field for my purposes. Something like this:
[image: ExampleTable]

Here's the code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'list files to tables
'http://allenbrowne.com/ser-59alt.html

Dim gCount As Long ' added by Crystal

Sub runListFiles()
    'Usage example.
    Dim strPath As String _
    , strFileSpec As String _
    , booIncludeSubfolders As Boolean

    strPath = "H:\Pictures\2019"
    strFileSpec = "*.*"
    booIncludeSubfolders = True

    ListFilesToTable strPath, strFileSpec, booIncludeSubfolders
End Sub

'crystal modified parameter specification for strFileSpec by adding default value
Public Function ListFilesToTable(strPath As String _
    , Optional strFileSpec As String = "*.*" _
    , Optional bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean _
    )
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   List the files in the path.
    'Arguments: strPath = the path to search.
    '           strFileSpec = "*.*" unless you specify differently.
    '           bIncludeSubfolders: If True, returns results from subdirectories of strPath as well.
    'Method:    FilDir() adds items to a collection, calling itself recursively for subfolders.

    Dim colDirList As New Collection
    Dim varitem As Variant
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

   Dim mStartTime As Date _
      , mSeconds As Long _
      , mMin As Long _
      , mMsg As String

   mStartTime = Now()
   '--------

    Call FillDirToTable(colDirList, strPath, strFileSpec, bIncludeSubfolders)

   mSeconds = DateDiff("s", mStartTime, Now())

   mMin = mSeconds \ 60
   If mMin > 0 Then
      mMsg = mMin & " min "
      mSeconds = mSeconds - (mMin * 60)
   Else
      mMsg = ""
   End If

   mMsg = mMsg & mSeconds & " seconds"

   MsgBox "Done adding " & Format(gCount, "#,##0") & " files from " & strPath _
      & IIf(Len(Trim(strFileSpec)) > 0, " for file specification --> " & strFileSpec, "") _
      & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & mMsg, , "Done"

Exit_Handler:
   SysCmd acSysCmdClearStatus
   '--------

    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, , "ERROR"

    'remove next line after debugged -- added by Crystal


    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

Private Function FillDirToTable(colDirList As Collection _
    , ByVal strFolder As String _
    , strFileSpec As String _
    , bIncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

    'Build up a list of files, and then add add to this list, any additional folders
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim vFolderName As Variant
    Dim strSQL As String

    'Add the files to the folder.
    strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
    strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)
    Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
         gCount = gCount + 1
         SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, gCount
         strSQL = "INSERT INTO Files " _
          & " (FPath) " _
          & " SELECT """ & strFolder & """" _
          & "& """ & strTemp & """;"
         CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
        colDirList.Add strFolder & strTemp
        strTemp = Dir
    Loop

    If bIncludeSubfolders Then
        'Build collection of additional subfolders.
        strTemp = Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)
        Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
            If (strTemp <> ".") And (strTemp <> "..") Then
                If (GetAttr(strFolder & strTemp) And vbDirectory) <> 0& Then
                    colFolders.Add strTemp
                End If
            End If
            strTemp = Dir
        Loop
        'Call function recursively for each subfolder.
        For Each vFolderName In colFolders
            Call FillDirToTable(colDirList, strFolder & TrailingSlash(vFolderName), strFileSpec, True)
        Next vFolderName
    End If

Exit_Handler:

    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Files " _
    & " (FPath) " _
    & " SELECT ""  ~~~ ERROR ~~~""" _
    & ", """ & strFolder & """;"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function

Public Function TrailingSlash(varIn As Variant) As String
    If Len(varIn) > 0& Then
        If Right(varIn, 1&) = "\" Then
            TrailingSlash = varIn
        Else
            TrailingSlash = varIn & "\"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The code provided does not output file path and name as one value, they are separate values. Did you post Allen's original code instead of your adapted version?

Comment: You're right. I updated the original post with what is partially working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a new variable:
`Dim strLocation As String`

Set variable and modify your SQL statement.

```
    'Add the files to the folder.
    strLocation = Mid(strFolder, InStrRev(strFolder, "\") + 1)
    strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
    strTemp = Dir(strFolder & strFileSpec)
    Do While strTemp <> vbNullString
         gCount = gCount + 1
         SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, gCount
         strSQL = "INSERT INTO Files (FPath, Location) " _
          & " SELECT '" & strFolder & strTemp & "','" & strLocation & "'"
         CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
         colDirList.Add strFolder & strTemp
         strTemp = Dir
    Loop
```

Assumes strFolder will not have a trailing slash when extracting last subfolder.   So maybe go with this version.

```
strFolder = TrailingSlash(strFolder)
strLocation = Left(strFolder, Len(strFolder) - 1)
strLocation = Mid(strLocation, InStrRev(strLocation, "\") + 1)
```

If you want to depend on final folder name always being 9 characters as stated in your comment, don't need strLocation variable.

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Files (FPath, Location) " & _
  "SELECT '" & strFolder & strTemp & "','" & Left(Mid(strFolder, Len(strFolder) - 9), 9) & "'"
```

Comment: This isn't quite working for me. How would I isolate the FPath and the Location value fields? 

I have updated my original post to reflect what is working to combine the file name and path in to one field.

Comment: And why is it not working - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Because it works for me. The code isolating those values is in the SQL. Ooops, I was using Debug.Print, not the SQL, in my test. Small but critical typo in the SQL syntax - was missing closing paren. I have edited. Or go back to the SELECT version instead of VALUES.

Comment: This is working to output the path and file name in the FPath field, but the Location field is not getting populated with anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, went and built table to test SQL. Went with creating a new variable because handling strFolder variable and trailing slash got too complicated. Revised Answer.

Comment: I was able to get your previous revision working by changing "+ 1" to "- 9". All of my location folders are 9 digits long. The only trouble is, there is a trailing backslash the output. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Then you are using Len() instead of InStrRev? Might review my latest edit of answer.